# Displaying an Array of Objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

Trying to populate a uitable from xml, xml is already parsed.

```
for (Row* fighter in parser.fighter) 
{   
    NSLog(@"%@",fighter.title);
    NSLog(@"%@",fighter.info);
    NSLog(@"%@",fighter.img);
    NSLog(@"=========");
}
```

prints out:

```
title0
info0
img0
=========
title1
info1
img1
=========
title2
info2
img2
=========
title3
info3
img3
=========
```

I'm trying to put the parsed data into an array that has 2 columns

ex. [[figher0, fighter1] , [fighter2, fighter3]]

```
NSMutableArray *holderArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSInteger i = 1; i < [parser.fighter count]; i+=2) {
    id object1 = [parser.fighter objectAtIndex:i-1];
    id object2 = [parser.fighter objectAtIndex:i];
    [holderArray addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:object1, object2, nil]];
}

for (int j=0; j< [holderArray count]; j++) {
    NSLog(@"%d :: %@",j, [holderArray objectAtIndex:j]);
    NSLog(@"=====",);   
}
```

prints out:

```
"<Row: 0x600c5f0>",
"<Row: 0x600c680>"
=========
"<Row: 0x600c640>",
"<Row: 0x6106f60>"
=========
"<Row: 0x600ee90>",
"<Row: 0x600eed0>"
=========
"<Row: 0x600ec60>",
"<Row: 0x600f0f0>"
=========
```

How do i access the data ie figher.title, fighter.info and fighter.img?

thanks

Comment: Your second example doesn't produce the output shown.  In fact, your second example doesn't even compile because of `NSLog(@"======",);`.  Also, what is rootArray?

Comment: i messed up typing it, rootArray is holderArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Using: -

```
NSMutableArray *holderArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSInteger i = 1; i < [parser.fighter count]; i+=2) {
id object1 = [parser.fighter objectAtIndex:i-1];
id object2 = [parser.fighter objectAtIndex:i];
[holderArray addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:object1, object2, nil]];
}

for (int j=0; j< [holderArray count]; j++) {
NSLog(@"%@ :: %@",[holderArray objectAtIndex:j].title, [holderArray objectAtIndex:j].info);
NSLog(@"=====",);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your last loop you are trying to print an array of two fighters. The array is only printed as a hex pointer. What you should do is to retrieve the elements of your inner array and collect them in a string:

```
for (int j=0; j< [rootArray count]; j++) {
    NSMutableString rowString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:100];
    [rowString appendFormat:@"[ "];
    for( Row* fighter in [rootArray objectAtIndex:j] ) {
       [rowString appendFormat:@"[%@, %@] ", fighter.title, fighter.info];
    }

    [rowString appendFormat:@"]"];
    NSLog(@"%d :: %@",j, rowString);
    if( j > 0 && j % 2 == 0 ) {
       NSLog(@"=====");   
    }
}
```

I have no compiler at hand so please check for syntax errors in my example by yourself ;-).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this

```
for (int j=0; j< [holderArray count]; j++) {
    NSLog(@"%d :: title = %@, info = %@",j, [holderArray objectAtIndex:j].title, [holderArray objectAtIndex:j].info);
    NSLog(@"=====",);   
}
```